# How do I make a transparent background-color that is on top of a background-image go to bottom?

Tags: html, css, layout, background-color

Okay, my problem is, I have a semi-transparent background-color on top of an image background. But when the computer screen is to big and page becomes longer vertically then horizontal the background-color stops after the content ends.
Example: [background-color end before the end of the page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RyyfK.jpg).
I have looked everywhere and tried it all (height: 100%; height:100vh; bottom:0; margin:0; etc.). 100% does nothing, when using 100vh the background-color stops when I scroll down, bottom/margin:0; nothing.

The code my using is this.

```
html {
  background: url(../images/back1.jpg) no-repeat center center fixed;
  -webkit-background-size: cover;
  -moz-background-size: cover;
  -o-background-size: cover;
  background-size: cover;
}

body {
  background-color: rgba(0, 34, 62, 0.7);
  margin: -0.5px;
  font-family: verdana, sans-serif;
  color: #b9c8d4;
  text-align: center;
 }
```

To see the website and the whole code go to: http://bienivitesse.com/juluwarlu/
If anyone knows any way to solve this, please let me know.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have applied your main background to the `html` tag directly. While possible, it is not such a good idea to be styling it directly, always use the body or direct-descendants for the sake of good practice.

I think you can't stack a color on top of an image using the `background` property, but what you can do is - you can set the blue background using **[css pseudo-elements](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/::after)**.

You will have to fiddle with the `z-index` property to get the divs to appear in the right order, so they won't be stuck under the color as well.

e.g.

```css
html {
  font-family: Arial, sans-serif;
}

.container {
  background: url('http://placekitten.com.s3.amazonaws.com/homepage-samples/408/287.jpg') no-repeat center center/cover;
  padding-bottom: 20rem;
  position: relative;
  z-index: 1;
}

.container::before {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  background: rgba(0, 34, 62, 0.7);
}

.wrapper {
  width: 70%;
  margin: 0 auto;
  z-index: 2;
  position: relative;
}

.content {
  padding: 4rem;
  color: #fff;
  background: purple;
  z-index: 3;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="wrapper">
    <div class="content">CONTENT</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I did this, but the same problem is still there. What I'll trying to do is make the semi-transparent background color stick to the bottom of the page. To make it completely cover the image. <br> Even your code example show my problem, as it only show the layer until the content ends. (I think I'm explaining this wrong, but thanks for the help)

Comment: @It'sSoCool , I understood just now, sorry for the confusion. Updated my answer.

Comment: Thanks a lot! That's almost it. The only thing now is, by adding padding-bottom: 20rem; the page keeps going past the footer when the page is wide screen. See, the problem I have only happens when the site is shown on a big monitor, the browser in longer vertically then horizontally and the content doesn't fill the entire page. But when the screen is small or longer horizontally I don't have an issue. So the padding isn't need then. Is there a way to only add the padding when these conditions are met?

Comment: I think that is some kind of a self-inflicted issue, but you can always set a media query breakpoint from on window width/height to another. But I suggest that you stick only to width, because height is always messy.http://learnlayout.com/media-queries.html